# Analyze stand alone Java Application locally for threads

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, monitoring

Respected Experts,

I have a stand alone java application and want to monitor the threads created by it. I am planning to use a tool like JConsole or JVisualVM. However, I am not able to connect these tools locally to my Java Application.

I am using Windows machine. JConsole and Java program are running locally. I have tried to run Java application with following JMV arguments with no success:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false LinkedListTest
```

When I try to connect using JConsole, my process id is greyed and following message appears:

- *Note: The management agent is not enabled on this process*

I think I should be able to connect JConsole to a stand alone java application. Any thoughts what I am missing here

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Try this instead: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote

Comment: Thanks @edhamed for your suggestion. This didn't help: java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote LinkedListTest

Comment: `JVisualVM` does not need these command line options for local Java applications. It will start the management agent itself through the attach API if it’s not already running. Just start `JVisualVM` and double-click on the right JVM in the provided list.

Comment: JConsole needs the -D ... As @Holger said JVisualVM doesn't. You probably have some other problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the inputs. I was able to solve the problem and the details are as follows:

As @Holger mentioned, both JConsole and JVisualVM can connect to the local Java Application running without any JMX arguments. The problem that I was facing was machine specific. I restarted the machine and deleted the following directory:

> %TMP%\hsperfdata_User.Name

(I was not able to delete this directory without doing a restart)

Restarted JConsole/JVisualVM and was able to connect to local java processes using the process id.
In fact, the use of JVisualVM pointed me towards this fix. On start of JVisualVM, I got an error message stating something like local processes/applications can't be monitored. The message had a link to [Troubleshooting guide](http://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html). I am reproducing the relevant snippet:

> Local Applications Cannot Be Monitored (Error Dialog On Startup)
>
> Description: An error dialog saying that local applications cannot be monitored is shown >immediately after VisualVM startup. Locally running Java applications are displayed as Application> (pid ###).
>
> Resolution:  This can happen on Windows systems if the username contains capitalized letters. In >this case, username is UserName but the jvmstat directory created by JDK is >%TMP%\hsperfdata_username. To workaround the problem, exit all Java applications, delete the >%TMP%\hsperfdata_username directory and create new %TMP%\hsperfdata_UserName directory.

However, on my machine directory had the following format:

> %TMP%\hsperfdata_User.Name

So, my recommendations are:
-check the name of the above mentioned directory for presence of camel case user name
-If not, follow the steps from the Trouble Shooting guide
-If the problem persists, delete the directory (may require machine reboot, as in my case)
-Restart JConsole/JVisualVM

Hopefully, the problem would be resolved.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Thanks for your explanation with deleting the folder!! That fixed my problem!! But, you do not have to restart your system. Only make sure, that Eclipse is not running and no Java processes in the task manager (OS: Windows 7).

Comment: Thanks @mrbela for your observation. If an application or a process is using a file or folder, windows won't allow deletion. So, closing/exiting such applications and process might help to avoid windows restart. Thanks and Regards